# how to pass multiple parameter in @Url.action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My javascript function is as follows

```
function SelectVoucher(Vid, vDeptCode) {
    var voucherID = Vid;
    var vDeptCode = vDeptCode;
    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Edit_Voucher", "Voucher", new { id = voucherID }) ";
}
```

but `new { id = voucherID }` gives me an error as:

> voucher id does not exists in current Context.

Comment: `@Url.Action()` is razor code. Its evaluated on the server before its sent to the view. `voucherID` is a javascript variable which does not even exist at that point. You need to generate the url youself - e.g. `"@Url.Action("Edit_Voucher", "Voucher") + '/' + voucherID;`

Comment: It will give you the error as voucherID is a javascript variable.

Comment: public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(properties.Select(x => new DataColumn(x.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(x.PropertyType) ?? x.PropertyType)).ToArray());
            source.Select(x => dt.NewRow().ItemArray = properties.Select(y => y.GetValue(x, null)).ToArray()).Map(x => dt.Rows.Add(x));
            return dt;
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the below Example

```
var firstname = "abc";
var username = "abcd";
location.href = '@Url.Action("Display", "Customer") ? 
                                     uname=' + firstname + '&name=' + username;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass it in the following way :

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Edit_Voucher", "Voucher", new { id = voucherID,name = customerName }) ";
```